# Why can't I call the correct div with parentNode and nextSibling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```js
const copyContent = async() => {
  try {
    let copyText = event.target.parentNode.lastChild.value;
    let copied = event.target.nextSibling.nextSibling;

    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
    console.log('Content copied to clipboard');
    copied.style.animation = "appear 4s linear";
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-container" onclick="copyContent()">
      <div>
        <img src="https://google.com">
        <span>#1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="copied">
        <span>Copied!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input class="link" type="text" value="https://google.com">
  </div>


  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-container" onclick="copyContent()">
      <div>
        <img src="https://yahoo.com">
        <span>#2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="copied">
        <span>Copied!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input class="link" type="text" value="https://yahoo.com">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the error I get:

> Failed to copy:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
> at copyContent

I know where I'm going wrong is here:

```
let copyText = event.target.parentNode.lastChild.value;

let copied = event.target.nextSibling.nextSibling;
```

But I've tried many different combinations and it doesn't work. I'm avoiding using an id because I'm going to have MANY "cards".

Comment: Inspect some intermediate values. Find out what `event.target`, `event.target.parentNode.lastChild`, `event.target.nextSibling`, and `event.target.nextSibling.nextSibling` are. Make sure you know what the difference between [`nextSibling`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) and [`nextElementSibling`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) is, as well as between [`lastChild`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild) and [`lastElementChild`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/lastElementChild).

Comment: Perhaps `event.target` is not what you think it is? Instead use [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to select a specific ancestor and work from there.

Comment: most of the time you want to use ElementNodes not just nodes because they can be text nodes and usally they are not that useful.

Comment: Look carefully at event.target.nextSibling.nextSibling - card-container has only one sibling (the input element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues that needed addressing:

1. Use of the global `event` window property is not advisable, particularly so in an `async` function that potentially could read an Event Object for an event that occurred after it was called.

   - If the event handler is added in an HTML onEventName attribute, pass `event` as an argument to the function called. (If you are wondering, 'event' is passed as an argument to a function generated by the HTML parser from the attribute's text value.)
   - Better would be to add the event handler in JavaScript using the `element.addEventListener` syntax.
2. Click event targets are the element that was under the mouse when clicked. In this case it could be one of sundry child elements at different levels of nesting within the `.card-container` division. While you *could* use `closest` to find the division, it's already available as `event.currentTarget` because that is where the event is being processed.
3. Element (getter) properties `nextSibling`, `previousSibing`, `firstChild` and `lastChild` are quite capable of returning text and HTML comment nodes - which is not what you want in this case. Use `nextElementSibling`, `previousElementSibling`, `firstElementChild` and `lastElementChild` versions instead when looking for elements.

Here's a reworked example, using a transition rather than an animation because it wasn't included in the post. The value copied to the clip board is the text content of the `input` element following the card container - amend if something else if supposed to be copied.

```js
"use strict";
const copyContent = async(event) => {  // takes event object argument
  try {
    let currentTarget = event.currentTarget; // should be div.card-container 
    const input = currentTarget.parentNode.lastElementChild;
    const copyText =input.value;

      console.log("currentTarget = %s.%s", currentTarget.tagName, currentTarget.className); // debug
      console.log("input: ", input)
      console.log( "copyText:", copyText);
    let copied = currentTarget.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling;
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
      console.log('Content copied to clipboard');
    copied.style.color = "forestgreen"; // simplified
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
  }
}
```

```css
.card-container {
  border: thin solid green;
  background-color: honeydew;
}
.copied { 
  color: white;
  transition: color 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards-container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-container" onclick="copyContent(event)">
            <div>
                <img src="http://example.com">
                <span>#1</span>
            </div>
           <div class="copied">
               <span>copied to clipboard</span>
           </div>
        </div>
       <input class="link" type="text" value="http://example.com">
  </div>


  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-container" onclick="copyContent(event)">
      <div>
        <img src="https://yahoo.com">
        <span>#2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="copied">
        <span>copied to clipboard</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input class="link" type="text" value="http://example.com">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a great explanation and worked perfectly! I also added `copied.style.animation = "none";` right after `let copied = currentTarget.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling;` so that the animation repeats every time it's clicked and it did the trick. Do you think that's the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Without looking I'd say probably - I don't work with animations much so for me it's look up the documentation every time :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not passing the event on the onclick, it should be
`onclick="copyContent(event)"`

Second, as some comments have mentioned, `event.target` maybe not the element you think. The onclick is attached to `card-container` div and all its child, so if you click the span with the text `Copied!`, the image or other thing the target will change.

A solution for this can be use `closest` method

```
const copyContent = async(event) => {
  try {
    //if parent node its the actual target, use actual target as parent node, instead search for the closest element that has card-container class
    let parentNode = event.target.classList.contains("card-container") ? event.target : event.target.closest(".card-container")
    //from the parent node, search for the input
    let copyText = parentNode.querySelector("input.link");
    //from the parent node, search the copied span element?
    let copied = parentNode.querySelector(".copied span)";

    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
    console.log('Content copied to clipboard');
    copied.style.animation = "appear 4s linear";
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy: ', err);
  }
}
```

Observation: I think making the function async should be unnecesary as also awaiting navigator

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting indicates that `event.target` is `null`, which means that the event object is not being passed to the `copyContent` function. One way to fix this is by passing the event object as an argument to the function.

```js
<div class="card-container" onclick="copyContent(event)">
```

Then in the function, you can reference the event passed as a parameter `const copyContent = async(event) => {...` . Also you may consider using `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target` in your function since the difference: target is the element that triggered the event (e.g., the user clicked on), and currentTarget is the element that the event listener is attached to. Another idea is to use querySelector to select the element as well.

```js
let copyText = event.currentTarget.parentNode.querySelector('.link').value;
let copied = event.currentTarget.querySelector('.copied'); //Not sure if this is what you want
```

You can use this querySelector method to select the element, so you don't have to use `parentNode` and `nextSibling`.